# Cannot find flatbuffers-1.4.0.jar

Tags: flatbuffers

A very simple/dumb question as the title suggests.

But I've spent hours into this and no luck yet.

I searched its official site: https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/, didn't find its jar.

I was hoping to find some instructions to download it source code and build a jar file like this for Thrift: https://thrift.apache.org/lib/java
But, no luck, so, anyone has any ideas please help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no .jar provided. You are supposed to include the files in `java/` and the generated code in your project manually.

(edit): FlatBuffers now on Maven Central: https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/issues/3946

Comment: Thanks for your response. I definitely included the files in my `java/`, but now the problem is that I don't know how to generate the file into a .jar: here's where I am right now: I downloaded flatbuffers.1.4.0.tar.gz, extracted it, used its CMake files to build it, then run make, after all these, there's still no *.jar file, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: cmake & make build the `flatc` compiler (which is written in C++). Again, no .jar is provided nor generated. By running `flatc --java myschema.fbs` you.ll get .java files to include in your project.

Comment: Right, thanks a lot! I confused myself, after cmake & make, then I compiled the java classes into class files and then put them into a *.jar file and then my project works now! Thank you so much @Aardappel